# Spatial plot error after changes to dataframe

Tags: r, plot, spatial

I was using the following code to plot a spatial plot successfully:

```
colours<-(brewer.pal(7, "Blues"))
brks<-classIntervals(EDdata2$SIRt, n=7, style="fixed",fixedBreaks=c(0,1,2,5.0,10.0,20,50,120))
plot(brks, pal=colours)
brks<-brks$brks
plot(EDdata2, col=colours[findInterval(EDdata2$SIRt, brks,
                             all.inside=TRUE)], axes=F, border=FALSE)
```

However I made some changes to the spatialpolygonsdataframe `EDdata2` by adding some extra columns and changing how `SIRt` is calculated (however it remains a column of numbers - they are just calculate differently)

Now when I try to run the plot code I get an error despite having made no changes to the plotting code:

```
Error in plot.default(...) : formal argument "axes" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Whats going on here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the package author of the unnamed package you used to create `EDdata2` defined a `plot` method for whatever class `EDdata2` might be that both used the `axes` argument and also used the triple dot mechanism to pass arguments to `plot.default` without filtering out that argument. (This does suggest that the package author didn't really want you to make your own axes, so you should investigate the help page for `plot.whatever` to see if it offers a mechanism for passing the values you want to use for 'at' and 'labels'.) You will need to do the spadework yourself (or edit your answer to make it more complete and reproducible) to investigate.

If this code is using the plot method for the SpatialPolygons-class in package:sp then the default value for axes is already FALSE.

```
help("SpatialPolygons-class", package="sp")
```

It is of course possible to mess this up by defining "F" to be something other than "FALSE" and then using `axes=F`. In the current instance it might be simpler to just remove that argument from the call.

Comment: Actually - I figured it out - I used a merge in my new version and that coerced EDdata2 from a spatial dataframe toa  dataframe. This is the source of the problem!! Thanks for your answer. I will green check it to close this off